# strtof with char pointer set to 0.0

Tags: c

The problem I am having is that

```
float strtof( const char *restrict str, char **restrict str_end );
```

Returns 0.0 if conversion is unsuccessful. Say I have the following code...

```
int main() {
   char* str = "0.0";
   char* end;
   float conversion = strtof(str, &end);
}
```

This will not tell me if the str is a valid string OR if the string is value 0.0. I want to return true if the str is a valid floating number, otherwise false.

Comment: You must check the value of `*end`. If it is a `'\0', then the whole string represents a floating point number.

Comment: @DYZ say i had a string like 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 which is smaller than FLT_MIN(making it an invalid) . What would the value of *end be?

Comment: From the manual page (have you read it?): "_If the correct value would cause overflow, plus or minus HUGE_VAL  (HUGE_VALF, HUGE_VALL) is returned (according to the sign of the value), and  ERANGE is stored in errno.  If the correct value would cause underflow, zero  is returned and ERANGE is stored in errno._" The value of `*end` would not matter in either case.

Comment: @DYZ thing is it is for a school assignment and i can not use the <errno.h> library so testing with define ERANGE would be impossible. Is there another method?

Comment: @JohnStevens, are you telling that some C teacher has told you to use function `strtof(3)` but has forbidden access to `errno` variable?  Yo need a course change or a teacher change, i'm afraid.  That's like telling you are to use the `sin(3)` mathematical function, but you cannot assign or use its returned value.